# Generating Thumbnail, Copying It To Directory & Saving it To Database

Tags: php

I am wanting to use a pre-authored script to generate a thumbnail of an image, and I need to modify it to my needs, by having it copy the saved file to another directory, and saving the filename to a mysql database. But I am unsure where to do that in the script, as I can't determine when the actual file is output by the script(lack of skill).

Any help is always appreciated, Lea.

The code that I would like to add to the script is as follows:

```
if( $new_height == "50" && $new_width == "50" ) {

// I WILL WRITE CODE HERE FOR SOME QUERY, AND TO COPY FILE

}
```

The pre-authored script:

```
/*
    TimThumb script created by Tim McDaniels and Darren Hoyt with tweaks by Ben Gillbanks
    http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

    MIT License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

    Paramters
    ---------
    w: width
    h: height
    zc: zoom crop (0 or 1)
    q: quality (default is 75 and max is 100)

    HTML example: <img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=/images/whatever.jpg&w=150&h=200&zc=1" alt="" />
*/

/*
$sizeLimits = array(
    "100x100",
    "150x150",
);
*/

define ('CACHE_SIZE', 250);     // number of files to store before clearing cache
define ('CACHE_CLEAR', 5);      // maximum number of files to delete on each cache clear
define ('VERSION', '1.09');     // version number (to force a cache refresh

$imageFilters = array(
    "1" => array(IMG_FILTER_NEGATE, 0),
    "2" => array(IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE, 0),
    "3" => array(IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, 1),
    "4" => array(IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 1),
    "5" => array(IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 4),
    "6" => array(IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT, 0),
    "7" => array(IMG_FILTER_EMBOSS, 0),
    "8" => array(IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR, 0),
    "9" => array(IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR, 0),
    "10" => array(IMG_FILTER_MEAN_REMOVAL, 0),
    "11" => array(IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, 0),
);

// sort out image source
$src = get_request("src", "");
if($src == "" || strlen($src) <= 3) {
    displayError("no image specified");
}

// clean params before use
$src = cleanSource($src);
// last modified time (for caching)
$lastModified = filemtime($src);

// get properties
$new_width      = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", get_request("w", 0));
$new_height     = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", get_request("h", 0));
$zoom_crop      = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", get_request("zc", 1));
$quality        = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", get_request("q", 80));
$filters        = get_request("f", "");

if ($new_width == 0 && $new_height == 0) {
    $new_width = 100;
    $new_height = 100;
}

// set path to cache directory (default is ./cache)
// this can be changed to a different location
$cache_dir = './cache';

// get mime type of src
$mime_type = mime_type($src);

// check to see if this image is in the cache already
check_cache( $cache_dir, $mime_type );

// if not in cache then clear some space and generate a new file
cleanCache();

ini_set('memory_limit', "30M");

// make sure that the src is gif/jpg/png
if(!valid_src_mime_type($mime_type)) {
    displayError("Invalid src mime type: " .$mime_type);
}

// check to see if GD function exist
if(!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
    displayError("GD Library Error: imagecreatetruecolor does not exist");
}

if(strlen($src) && file_exists($src)) {

    // open the existing image
    $image = open_image($mime_type, $src);
    if($image === false) {
        displayError('Unable to open image : ' . $src);
    }

    // Get original width and height
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    // don't allow new width or height to be greater than the original
    if( $new_width > $width ) {
        $new_width = $width;
    }
    if( $new_height > $height ) {
        $new_height = $height;
    }

    // generate new w/h if not provided
    if( $new_width && !$new_height ) {

        $new_height = $height * ( $new_width / $width );

    } elseif($new_height && !$new_width) {

        $new_width = $width * ( $new_height / $height );

    } elseif(!$new_width && !$new_height) {

        $new_width = $width;
        $new_height = $height;

    }

    // create a new true color image
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
    imagealphablending($canvas, false);
    // Create a new transparent color for image
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    // Completely fill the background of the new image with allocated color.
    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $color);
    // Restore transparency blending
    imagesavealpha($canvas, true);

    if( $zoom_crop ) {

        $src_x = $src_y = 0;
        $src_w = $width;
        $src_h = $height;

        $cmp_x = $width  / $new_width;
        $cmp_y = $height / $new_height;

        // calculate x or y coordinate and width or height of source

        if ( $cmp_x > $cmp_y ) {

            $src_w = round( ( $width / $cmp_x * $cmp_y ) );
            $src_x = round( ( $width - ( $width / $cmp_x * $cmp_y ) ) / 2 );

        } elseif ( $cmp_y > $cmp_x ) {

            $src_h = round( ( $height / $cmp_y * $cmp_x ) );
            $src_y = round( ( $height - ( $height / $cmp_y * $cmp_x ) ) / 2 );

        }

        imagecopyresampled( $canvas, $image, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $new_width, $new_height, $src_w, $src_h );

    } else {

        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        imagecopyresampled( $canvas, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

    }

    if ($filters != "") {
        // apply filters to image
        $filterList = explode("|", $filters);
        foreach($filterList as $fl) {
            $filterSettings = explode(",", $fl);
            if(isset($imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]])) {

                for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++) {
                    if(!isset($filterSettings[$i])) {
                        $filterSettings[$i] = null;
                    }
                }

                switch($imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]][1]) {

                    case 1:

                        imagefilter($canvas, $imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]][0], $filterSettings[1]);
                        break;

                    case 2:

                        imagefilter($canvas, $imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]][0], $filterSettings[1], $filterSettings[2]);
                        break;

                    case 3:

                        imagefilter($canvas, $imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]][0], $filterSettings[1], $filterSettings[2], $filterSettings[3]);
                        break;

                    default:

                        imagefilter($canvas, $imageFilters[$filterSettings[0]][0]);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // output image to browser based on mime type
    show_image($mime_type, $canvas, $cache_dir);

    // remove image from memory
    imagedestroy($canvas);

} else {

    if(strlen($src)) {
        displayError("image " . $src . " not found");
    } else {
        displayError("no source specified");
    }

}

/**
 * 
 */
function show_image($mime_type, $image_resized, $cache_dir) {

    global $quality;

    // check to see if we can write to the cache directory
    $is_writable = 0;
    $cache_file_name = $cache_dir . '/' . get_cache_file();

    if(touch($cache_file_name)) {

        // give 666 permissions so that the developer 
        // can overwrite web server user
        chmod($cache_file_name, 0666);
        $is_writable = 1;

    } else {

        $cache_file_name = NULL;
        header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type);

    }

    $quality = floor($quality * 0.09);

    imagepng($image_resized, $cache_file_name, $quality);

    if($is_writable) {
        show_cache_file($cache_dir, $mime_type);

    }

    imagedestroy($image_resized);

    displayError("error showing image");

}

/**
 * 
 */
function get_request( $property, $default = 0 ) {

    if( isset($_REQUEST[$property]) ) {

        return $_REQUEST[$property];

    } else {

        return $default;

    }

}

/**
 * 
 */
function open_image($mime_type, $src) {

    if(stristr($mime_type, 'gif')) {

        $image = imagecreatefromgif($src);

    } elseif(stristr($mime_type, 'jpeg')) {

        @ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

    } elseif( stristr($mime_type, 'png')) {

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($src);

    }

    return $image;

}

/**
 * clean out old files from the cache
 * you can change the number of files to store and to delete per loop in the defines at the top of the code
 */
function cleanCache() {

    $files = glob("cache/*", GLOB_BRACE);

    $yesterday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60);

    if (count($files) > 0) {

        usort($files, "filemtime_compare");
        $i = 0;

        if (count($files) > CACHE_SIZE) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {

                $i ++;

                if ($i >= CACHE_CLEAR) {
                    return;
                }

                if (filemtime($file) > $yesterday) {
                    return;
                }

                unlink($file);

            }

        }

    }

}

/**
 * compare the file time of two files
 */
function filemtime_compare($a, $b) {

    return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);

}

/**
 * determine the file mime type
 */
function mime_type($file) {

    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) { 
        $os = 'WIN';
    } else { 
        $os = PHP_OS;
    }

    $mime_type = '';

    if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    // use PECL fileinfo to determine mime type
    if (!valid_src_mime_type($mime_type)) {
        if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
            finfo_close($finfo);
        }
    }

    // try to determine mime type by using unix file command
    // this should not be executed on windows
    if (!valid_src_mime_type($mime_type) && $os != "WIN") {
        if (preg_match("/FREEBSD|LINUX/", $os)) {
            $mime_type = trim(@shell_exec('file -bi "' . $file . '"'));
        }
    }

    // use file's extension to determine mime type
    if (!valid_src_mime_type($mime_type)) {

        // set defaults
        $mime_type = 'image/png';
        // file details
        $fileDetails = pathinfo($file);
        $ext = strtolower($fileDetails["extension"]);
        // mime types
        $types = array(
            'jpg'  => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png'  => 'image/png',
            'gif'  => 'image/gif'
        );

        if (strlen($ext) && strlen($types[$ext])) {
            $mime_type = $types[$ext];
        }

    }

    return $mime_type;

}

/**
 * 
 */
function valid_src_mime_type($mime_type) {

    if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg|gif|png/i", $mime_type)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

/**
 * 
 */
function check_cache($cache_dir, $mime_type) {

    // make sure cache dir exists
    if (!file_exists($cache_dir)) {
        // give 777 permissions so that developer can overwrite
        // files created by web server user
        mkdir($cache_dir);
        chmod($cache_dir, 0777);
    }

    show_cache_file($cache_dir, $mime_type);

}

/**
 * 
 */
function show_cache_file($cache_dir) {

    $cache_file = $cache_dir . '/' . get_cache_file();

    if (file_exists($cache_file)) {

        $gmdate_mod = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($cache_file));

        if(! strstr($gmdate_mod, "GMT")) {
            $gmdate_mod .= " GMT";
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"])) {

            // check for updates
            $if_modified_since = preg_replace("/;.*$/", "", $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]);

            if ($if_modified_since == $gmdate_mod) {
                header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
                exit;
            }

        }

        $fileSize = filesize($cache_file);

        // send headers then display image
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Last-Modified: " . $gmdate_mod);
        header("Content-Length: " . $fileSize);
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=9999, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: " . $gmdate_mod);

        readfile($cache_file);

        exit;

    }

}

/**
 * 
 */
function get_cache_file() {

    global $lastModified;
    static $cache_file;

    if(!$cache_file) {
        $cachename = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . VERSION . $lastModified;
        $cache_file = md5($cachename) . '.png';
    }

    return $cache_file;

}

/**
 * check to if the url is valid or not
 */
function valid_extension ($ext) {

    if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg|png|gif/i", $ext)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}

/**
 * tidy up the image source url
 */
function cleanSource($src) {

    // remove slash from start of string
    if(strpos($src, "/") == 0) {
        $src = substr($src, -(strlen($src) - 1));
    }

    // remove http/ https/ ftp
    $src = preg_replace("/^((ht|f)tp(s|):\/\/)/i", "", $src);
    // remove domain name from the source url
    $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $src = str_replace($host, "", $src);
    $host = str_replace("www.", "", $host);
    $src = str_replace($host, "", $src);

    // don't allow users the ability to use '../' 
    // in order to gain access to files below document root

    // src should be specified relative to document root like:
    // src=images/img.jpg or src=/images/img.jpg
    // not like:
    // src=../images/img.jpg
    $src = preg_replace("/\.\.+\//", "", $src);

    // get path to image on file system
    $src = get_document_root($src) . '/' . $src;    

    return $src;

}

/**
 * 
 */
function get_document_root ($src) {

    // check for unix servers
    if(@file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $src)) {
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }

    // check from script filename (to get all directories to timthumb location)
    $parts = array_diff(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), explode('/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $path .= $part . '/';
        if (file_exists($path . $src)) {
            return $path;
        }
    }   

    // the relative paths below are useful if timthumb is moved outside of document root
    // specifically if installed in wordpress themes like mimbo pro:
    // /wp-content/themes/mimbopro/scripts/timthumb.php
    $paths = array(
        ".",
        "..",
        "../..",
        "../../..",
        "../../../..",
        "../../../../.."
    );

    foreach($paths as $path) {
        if(@file_exists($path . '/' . $src)) {
            return $path;
        }
    }

    // special check for microsoft servers
    if(!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
        $path = str_replace("/", "\\", $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']);
        $path = str_replace($path, "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

        if( @file_exists( $path . '/' . $src ) ) {
            return $path;


        }
    }   

    displayError('file not found ' . $src);

}

/**
 * generic error message
 */
function displayError($errorString = '') {

    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    die($errorString);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload images.

By default, all images which are uploaded, are stored on the web servers temp dir (which is defined in the php init file).

Then I just use `resize_save_jpeg( $sourceFile, $targetFile, 480, 480, 80);` to resize image and save it in new directory.

`$sourceFile`is the path+filename of the image in the temp directory, and the `$targetfile` is the path+filename to the new thumbnail image.

The `80` is the jpeg quality. For thumbnails, I think 60 would be more than enough.

Here is the resize code. I don't remember where I got it from:

```
function resize_save_jpeg( $sourcefile, $targetfile, $target_image_width, $target_image_height, $quality )
{
    list( $source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type ) = getimagesize( $sourcefile );
    switch ( $source_image_type )
    {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif( $sourcefile );
        break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $sourcefile );
        break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng( $sourcefile );
        break;
    }

    if ( $source_gd_image === false )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $source_aspect_ratio = $source_image_width / $source_image_height;
    $target_aspect_ratio = $target_image_width / $target_image_height;

    if ( $source_image_width <= $target_image_width && $source_image_height <= $target_image_height ) {
        $target_image_width = $source_image_width;
        $target_image_height = $source_image_height;
    }
    elseif ( $target_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio ) {
        $target_image_width = ( int ) ( $target_image_height * $source_aspect_ratio );
    }
    else {
        $target_image_height = ( int ) ( $target_image_width / $source_aspect_ratio );
    }

    $target_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $target_image_width, $target_image_height );
    imagecopyresampled( $target_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $target_image_width, $target_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height );
    imagejpeg( $target_gd_image, $targetfile, $quality );
    imagedestroy( $source_gd_image );
    imagedestroy( $target_gd_image );
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**
Ups - missed the database part.

I would never saved the image itself to database. I would just create a reference to the image. By reference, I mean the pathname to the image.

To ensure that you have unique image names, you can create a MD5 from the server time, and use this as the filename. Then in your database, you just store the path or name (or both).

So after the image is saved, add the path/filname to DB.

**EDIT 2**

The [$_FILES attribute](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) is a global variable which contains an array of values (see link).
I use this + [getimagesize](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to retrieve the data I want:

```
$sourceFile   = $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
$fileInfo   = getimagesize($_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ]);
$filename   = md5(date("F d, Y H:i:s", time()));
$extension  = getExts($fileInfo[2]);        
$targetFile = "my/static/path".$filename.$extension;

// Get file extension from file binary.
function getExts($filetype) 
{
    switch ($filetype) {
        case "1": return "gif"; break;
        case "2": return "jpg"; break;
        case "3": return "png"; break;
        return "0"; break;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how I define $sourceFile, $targetFile exactly...?

Comment: And yes, I plan to save only the filename to the database:)